# How to disable external schema downloads in NuSoap

Tags: php, soap, schema, xsd, nusoap

One of our systems depends on a legacy application implemented in PHP, that uses NuSoap to query some SOAP webservices

Whenever it tries to connect to a webservice it also tries to download the schema from  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/  and we have noticed that in the last few days that website has had some intermitent outages, and that causes the webapp to fail, even when the webservices that it consumes are working fine.

Is there anyway we can configure (or patch) NuSoap to disable the validation against that external resource?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding style is set by default to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/. This is pre-set by NuSOAP as the SOAP-ENC element of the public array called namespaces. To change it, simply include a line in your script like:

```
$namespaces[SOAP-ENC] = 'http://my.special.encoding';
```

For more info see: http://developer.apple.com/internet/webservices/soapphp.html